# How do boost operators work?

Tags: c++, boost, operators, operator-overloading

`boost::operators` automatically defines operators like `+` based on manual implementations like `+=` which is very useful. To generate those operators for `T`, one inherits from `boost::operators<T>` as shown by the boost example:

`class MyInt : boost::operators<MyInt>`

I am familiar with the CRTP pattern, but I fail to see how it works here. Specifically, I am not really inheriting any facilities since the operators aren't members. `boost::operators` seems to be completely empty, but I'm not very good at reading boost source code.

Could anyone explain how this works in detail? Is this mechanism well-known and widely used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a big multiple inheritance chain, at the top of which there are a number of classes that implement the operators, but do so as `friend` functions, thus placing them in the enclosing namespace rather than as members of the class.

For example, the final implementation of `operator+` becomes:

```
template <class T, class U, class B = ::boost::detail::empty_base<T> >
struct addable2 : B
{                                                                  
  friend T operator +( T lhs, const U& rhs ) { return lhs += rhs; }
  friend T operator +( const U& lhs, T rhs ) { return rhs += lhs; }
};
```

Comment: What's really fun is that you inherit privately from the class and yet it works. It's a funny trick really :)

Comment: It has a name: the [Barton-Nackman trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton-Nackman_trick).