# How boost::operators are worked?

Tags: c++, boost, crtp

I found this question [How do boost operators work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958142/how-do-boost-operators-work) , but I still don't understand how this is works.

If I has `Point` class:

```
class Point : public boost::operators<Point> {
private:
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

`operator+` should know everything about `Point` fields but in what way `boost::operators` generate `operator+`(where it adds x and y) if we doesn't have reflection in C++.

Comment: It generates `operator+` based on `operator+=` which you need to implement.

Comment: @interjay great!

Comment: @interjay and the copy constructor, which can be implicit or `default`ed